# How to create nested comment and reply tree with a common table expression

Tags: postgresql, sorting, common-table-expression

I thought I had solved this, but alas I haven't.

I am looking to get PostgreSQL to pump out comments and replies in an order that can be rendered client side with no additional sort.

I have the following common table expression which I have tried multiple things with but I have yet to get the output I need.

```
WITH RECURSIVE comment_tree AS (
SELECT 
    id           AS cte_id, 
    reply_to     AS cte_reply_to, 
    "createdAt"  AS cte_date, 
    body         AS cte_body, 
    commenter_id AS cte_commenter_id, 
    1            AS level, 
    ARRAY[0]     AS sort, 
    article_id 
FROM "Comments" 
WHERE reply_to IS NULL 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    c.reply_to, 
    c."createdAt", 
    c.body, 
    c.commenter_id, 
    p.level + 1     AS level, 
    p.sort || p.level, 
    c.article_id 
FROM "Comments" c 
JOIN comment_tree p ON c.reply_to = p.cte_id) 
SELECT 
    sort,
    cte_body         AS body, 
    cte_id           AS id, 
    cte_reply_to     AS reply_to, 
    cte_date         AS "createdAt", 
    cte_commenter_id AS commenter_id, 
    level 
FROM comment_tree 
ORDER BY sort
```

The result of this is as follows.

[image]

What i need is

[image]

How can I get the sort to reproduce the manually created body column?

Comment: I am a bit unclear on your question as your select statement is sorting by the column named 'sort' and you desire the sort to use the 'body' column.  Am I missing something?

Comment: "Body" would normally be user entered text. I have manually entered that text for the demo to be able to see whether I had managed to achieve the correct ordering. I need "Sort" to have the same content as body but generated programatically.

Comment: Im looking for the same, did you figure it out?

Comment: @21st Sorry about the delay in replying. I have added the code (in the answer) that I ended up using to sort the comments after returning them all from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I ended up using. After returning all the items from the database I checked each top level comment for children then recursively checked them for children until none were found.

```
function(data){

    // Initialise 
    var comments = data[0];
    var topLevelComments = [];
    var commentsByReplyToValue = {}; 
    var commentsSorted = [];

    // Split 
    for(var i = comments.length -1; i >= 0; i--){ 
        if(comments[i].reply_to == null){ 
            topLevelComments.push(comments.splice(i,1)[0]); 
        }
    }

    for(var j = comments.length -1; j >= 0; j--){ 
        var currentReplyTo = comments[j].reply_to;

        if(commentsByReplyToValue.hasOwnProperty(currentReplyTo)){ 
            commentsByReplyToValue[currentReplyTo].push(comments.splice(i,1)[0]);
        }else{ 
            commentsByReplyToValue[currentReplyTo] = [];
            commentsByReplyToValue[currentReplyTo].push(comments.splice(i,1)[0]);
        }

    }

    // Sort Top Levels 
    sortByDateAsc(topLevelComments);


    // Sort Lower Levels
    var replyToKey, obj, prop, owns = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
    for (replyToKey in commentsByReplyToValue ) {
        if (owns.call(commentsByReplyToValue, replyToKey)) {
            sortByDateDesc(commentsByReplyToValue[replyToKey]);
        }
    }

    //Join together 
    findChildren(topLevelComments, commentsByReplyToValue, commentsSorted); 


    return commentsSorted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

row_number() function can help you:

```
WITH RECURSIVE comment_tree AS (
SELECT
    id           AS cte_id,
    parent_id    AS cte_parent_id,
    author_id    AS cte_author_id,
    body         AS cte_body,
    is_hidden    AS cte_is_hidden,
    created_at  AS cte_created_at,
    1::bigint            AS level,
    ARRAY[row_number() over (order by created_at)] AS sort
FROM news.comments c
WHERE c.parent_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.parent_id,
    c.author_id,
    c.body,
    c.is_hidden    AS is_hidden,
    c.created_at,
    p.level + 1     AS level,
    p.sort || row_number() over (partition by parent_id order by created_at)
FROM news.comments c
JOIN comment_tree p ON c.parent_id = p.cte_id)
SELECT
    cte_body         AS body,
    cte_id           AS id,
    cte_parent_id    AS parent_id,
    cte_created_at   AS created_at,
    cte_author_id    AS author_id,
    cte_is_hidden    AS is_hidden,
    sort,
    level
FROM comment_tree ct
ORDER BY sort
```